# Titanium : PayPal library in Alloy

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-alloy

I need to implement older PayPal library in the Titanium Alloy project.

When I tried to download [this](https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/4978?restoreSearch=true#!overview) module , but I've got 400 error code.

Also I can't find any solution in the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it. You need to [this](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paypal/mobile/android/dist) directory and download the module. Then I intalled if with Help->Install Titanium Module.

And this worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Use this module link.It is being constantly updated by titanium appcelerator

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paypal

Thanks

Comment: thank you. and what about the older PayPal library releasing, not the MPL ?

Comment: Do not know about that miuch

Comment: Tell me please, did you implement this module in any of your applications ?

Comment: Nope i have not used that in any of my app but i think it should work fine was it creating problem

Comment: I don't know, I tried really a lot ways to solve it, but nothing yet.

Comment: There is another module that i have tried myself but that involves credit card too

Comment: @Wahhab_mirza Kindly can you share the link of PayPal module that work with Android. It seems that appcelerator module for PayPal: https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.paypal does not work with Android. Kindly guide!.